# Module not imported running python script at startup

Tags: python, service, raspberry-pi, importerror, autostart

For context, I am using Raspberry Pi model 3B+. Currently I am trying to run a python script at the Pi's boot up. The script uses the module face_recognition, and everything works fine when running it normally or through the terminal.
But as soon as I try running it automatically when the pi boots up I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/code/please_work_2.py", line 6, in <module>
    import face_recognition
ImportError: No module named face_recognition
```

I googled a bit and I think it has to do something with not setting the environment in the service file correctly. It is a bit messy as of right now, but I am new to working with these kind of files so I am struggling with finding out how to get it to work. My service file right now:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Bling

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/facial_recognition
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
Environment="prog_path"=/home/pi/facial_recognition
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/facial_recognition/run_on_start.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
KillMode=process
TimeoutSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

The program does not necessarily need to run in Desktop auto-login so if there is a possible fix in the console version that is fine as well. I just have it this way currently, so it is easier to check if the program is working as intended.

EDIT:
I have also tried using crontab, but then nothing happened on reboot. Not with and not without the '&' at the end.
As of right now, as was suggested below is that when I add

```
User = pi
```

the program does launch, but I am struggling with getting it to launch once instead every 10s. Deleting that bit does not help since then it stops launching at all.

Comment: does it work if you use crontab? https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/how-to-run-a-script-at-start-up-on-a-raspberry-pi-using-crontab/

Comment: can you show me how you imported the modules in your python script?

Comment: I've never worked with Pi before but you definitely need to install your modules on to it before running the script. On your dev environment, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in your terminal, copy this file to your environment in Pi and then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` in Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, add the following `User=pi` under `[Service]` and see if it works.

I think the way you did it, you are trying to launch as another user or sudo user, you have your stuff only installed in your current pi user path, so try launching the script as the user pi.

Your service file should look like this.

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Bling

[Service]
User=pi
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/facial_recognition
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
Environment="prog_path"=/home/pi/facial_recognition
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/facial_recognition/run_on_start.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
KillMode=process
TimeoutSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Comment: This indeed resolved the error. The program is now launches and works, but every 10 seconds the program is ran again. I just want it to launch once when the system boots up. I already tried adjusting or deleting the

Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
KillMode=process
TimeoutSec=infinity

bit but then it does not launch at all

Comment: If I only delete the RestartSec=10s, then it just keeps spam running the program instantly instead of every 10 seconds.

Comment: @Luc did you reload the reenable and reload the service file?

Comment: Yes I did. Now the pi just instantly runs the program infinitely and I can't get it to stop causing it to freeze after about 10-15 seconds needing to pull the power in order to get in again. Any command I can instantly run to stop this? Tried the sudo systemctl stop but that does not work

Comment: @Luc i have edited my code, does it work now ?

Comment: @Luc honestly, I have solved the python part of the program already. You should mark this correct and post your question on https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ because the question is more related to linux startup and not python already.

Comment: Yes you're right, does not launch as of right now but you indeed did resolve the initial issue, will try to figure that out somewhere else. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Luc try https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ or https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewforum.php?f=29&sid=bd65d711c30f31ce129153b8f4f1d5bb you will find the answer quite fast. It is not specific to the raspberry pi im sure.